# iOS biometrics, how to create LAContext instance from C++?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to implement biometric authentication on iOS from a C++ codebase. Here is [one example](https://www.devfright.com/touch-id-tutorial-objective-c/).

In order to achieve this, I need to use the LAContext obj-c APIs. However, when I try to initialize the class from C++ I get a pointer/reference error:

```cpp
// Cannot initialize a variable of type 'LAContext *__strong' with an rvalue of type 'LAContext'
LAContext* authContext = LAContext();
```

Is there any way to achieve this? Or is this struct available from Obj-c only?

Edit 1:

My file is in Obj-C++, so in theory I should be able to mix C++ and Obj-C code, however when I try to write a Obj-C function to alloc the LAContext object I get a missing symbols error:

```objectivec
-(bool)biometricsAvailable {
    LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
    NSError *authError = nil;
    return true;
}
```

On the compilation step this error is thrown:

```
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_LAContext
```

XCode itself does not show any error while editing the file, only happens when I try to build/compile the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was not with mixing C++ and Obj-C code, but rather with my library being linked via cocoapods and the LocalAuthentication framework being missing.

I needed to add:

```rb
s.frameworks = "LocalAuthentication"
```

to the podspec and creating a LAContext instance works just fine.